# How to save handle object hierarchy to disk in matlab

Tags: matlab, serialization, save

I have some big handle objects hierarchy, for example

```
classdef A < handle
    b;
    c;
end

classdef B < handle
    d;
    e;
end

classdef C < handle
    f;
    g;
end

a = A;
```

where `a,b,c,d,e,f` are all instances of their respective classes. Eventually, there are basic data types (vectors or scalars of, say, double).

I need the save of `a` to hold all the information about `a,b,c,d,e,f`, in a way that can be restored later.

Runtime is not an issue for me right now.

Development time is an issue.

How can I easily create a save of the top A type object to disk? (a deep copy, to disk).

I want it to happen automatically (built in), somewhat like java's serialize maybe, without me having to change some save method for every change I make in the classes' structure.

Comment: What wrong with Matlab's `save`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When saving objects with MATLAB using the built-in [`save`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html), it will automatically save a "deep-copy" in that it saves all properties of the object and if any of those properties are *also* objects or arrays of object, they will themselves be serialized. The objects can then easily be loaded again using the built-in [`load`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/load.html) function. It is worth noting that in order for an object of a custom class to be loaded properly, the class definition must be on the path when calling `load`.

```
save('output.mat', 'a')
fromdisk = load('output.mat');
```

If you want to customize the saving or loading functionality of your class, you can overload the [`saveobj`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/saveobj.html) and [`loadobj`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/loadobj.html) methods, respectively.

Comment: Im sorry, I forgot to inherit from handle, fixing it now. Does save also work for classed that inherit handle (meaning all members are by reference)?

Comment: @Gulzar Yes if you have two references to the same instance, they are loaded back in as references to the same handle object as well.